# why c++ openMP program execute longer

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I've problem with understanding how it's possible.
I've long textfile (ten thousand lines), i read it to 
variable **text** as string. I'd like to split it on 200 parts.
I've written this code using openMP directives:

```
    std::string str[200];

    omp_set_num_threads(200);
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            str[i]= text.substr(i*(text.length()/200),text.length()/200);
        }
    }
```

and it's execution time is 231059 us

if i write it as sequence

```
        for (int i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            str[i]= text.substr(i*(text.length()/200),text.length()/200);
        }
```

execution time is 215902us

Am I using openMP wrong, or what's happen here

Comment: You'll probably have to loop a lot more than just 200 times (or do a lot more work in the body) to overcome the overhead of multithreading.

Comment: What is the reason to use 200 threads? You really have a computer a computer with that number of cores? Otherwise, you are just asking your cores to spend time switching threads to simulate a larger parallel computer. And using more cores to solve a problem means more ALU, adders, multipliers, etc, and is useful if you do many computations. But is does not mean more memory or more memory bandwidth and your program is definitely memory bound.

Answer (score 1):

substr causes a memory allocation and a memcpy, and not much else. So instead of 1 thread asking the OS for some ram, you now have N threads asking the OS for some RAM, at the same time. This isn't a great design.

Splitting a workload to be tackled by a thread group makes a lot of sense when the workload is CPU intensive. It makes a no sense at all, when all of those threads are competing for the same shared resource (e.g. the ram). One thread will simply block all the others until each allocation has been completed.